# centering titles when using the beamer class in latex

Tags: latex, beamer

I want to center the frametitles on my talk.  I understand that the beamer class has a built-in ability to center frametitles, but I can't figure out how to do it.  It is something like:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle[alignment=center]{title}
\end{frame}
```

but that doesn't work.

Can I get a little help?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
```

before all slides.

Answer (score 3):

Manually, i always did it like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\centerline{Hello World!}}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better to put this code at preamble of your document. So you'll have both frame title and subtitle centered:

```
\makeatletter 
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{% 
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{% 
    \gdef\insertframetitle{\centering{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0
        \relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}% 
  \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}% 
  \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}% 
}% 
} 
\makeatother
```